# UIButtonTypeInfoDark Touch Area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've added a `UIButton` with a type of `UIButtonTypeInfoDark` to a view and the touch area for it is huge. I know Apple recommends 44px, but in this case it's quite a bit larger. I set a light gray background for the view to see where the end area for 44px is and I'm able touch outside the light gray view area and still receive the `infoTapped:` event.

Can anyone clarify as to why? Thanks!

```
_infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
[_infoButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:NO];
[_infoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width-44, 0, 44, 25)];
[_infoButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[_infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Try setting the center instead of the frame. Then NSLog its exact frame in the infoTapped. I'd be interested to know its exact value.

Comment: I used the code below and get the following log (x, y, width, height). It must be resetting the touch area outside my view coords to 44px wide.

75.000000 0.000000 18.000000 18.000000

[_infoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width - 25, 0, 18, 18)];
[_infoButton setCenter:CGPointMake(frame.size.width-25+9, 9)];

Comment: i will recommend you to check this question [Getting or setting the hit area of UIButtonTypeInfoLight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762271/getting-or-setting-the-hit-area-of-uibuttontypeinfolight). its not a solution but a little help from my side.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this would most likely require subclassing.  You can override [`pointInside:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside%3awithEvent%3a) in a `UIButton` subclass and return `NO` unless strictly within the bounds of the button:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point);
}
```

Apple controls sometimes return `YES` to queries outside of their bounds to make the control easier to touch with a finger.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler version of checking whether the user touch inside or outside the info button bounds. Just check the status of touchInside.

```
if ([control isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)control;

    if (btn.buttonType == UIButtonTypeInfoDark && btn.touchInside == YES) {
        // User pressed button inside bounds...
    } else if (btn.buttonType == UIButtonTypeInfoDark && btn.touchInside == NO) {
        // User pressed button outside bounds...
    }
}
```