# Getting or setting the hit area of UIButtonTypeInfoLight

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicontrolevents

So it seems that the tappable area of an UIButton with the type of UIButtonTypeInfoLight is much larger than its frame. Because of this, I can not put a button right next to it, trying to tap it will tap the info button instead.

```
_infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, height);
_searchButton.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(_infoButton.frame), 0, 40, height);
```

Does anyone have any insite on how to get the tappable area of the button?

Edit:having the button next the info button it is not my core question (just an illustration of why it might be important). My question is about finding out the "hit area" for a button of these types.

Comment: Did you check if the info button is in front or in the back of the search button?

Comment: Dude button type of  UIButtonTypeInfoLight dimensions by default are 18 x 19. Why in the world are you making it 40 x height??

Comment: @SamBudda I'm doing that so that the button is centered in the frame I provided for it. Even with those default dimensions, its "hit area" goes beyond that frame, It's that area I'd like more info on

Comment: you are correct. i have tested it by myself. the hit area of the info button is more than @2x . i searched for it but no clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about looking up the specific rect of the hit area from code, but there is a way that you can specifically set the area that will be tappable. You can subclass your `UIButton` and override `UIView`'s `hitTest:withEvent:` to set the area. Here's an example that shows expanding the hit area, but I'm pretty sure you could use it to decrease the area as well: [Larger Hit Area for UIButton](http://bdunagan.com/2010/03/01/iphone-tip-larger-hit-area-for-uibutton/)

I suppose you could use trial and error with this method to tap areas and find out what is or isn't within the hit area's bounds. I know it's not ideal, but that's what I've found.

Comment: I guess that's the best answer out there. It's weird how the hit area is larger but not defined anywhere. Good tip on checking it though